# Any stopping time $S_n$ in $\{S_n\leq T\}$ must be constant

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let the filtration by defined by $\mathcal{F}_t= \sigma (\{T\leq s\}_{s\leq t})$.

Let $S_n$ be a stopping time, with respect to the above filtration, and $T$ be a random time with values in $[0,\infty[$.

The book I'm reading states that we must have $S_n$ constant in the event $\{S_n < T\}$. Why is that?